# How to hide a button/input element according to the string in value?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Browse Server" class="button">
```

And I would like to hide this button using jQuery or just assign him some css and hide it via CSS stylesheet. I guess I have to use `.val()`, but how to search all html document to find input elements with value "Browse Server"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('input[value="Browse Server"]').hide();
```